# Oracle function compilation error with no errors

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am creating a function, logged in as sys.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Core.Get_Contact_Code
(
       First_Name IN NVARCHAR2,
       Middle_Name IN  NVARCHAR2,
       Last_Name IN NVARCHAR2
) 
RETURN NVARCHAR2 
IS 
    Ret_Val NVARCHAR2(10);
    C_Code NVARCHAR2(10);

    CURSOR contact_cursor IS 
    SELECT Contact_Code FROM (
        SELECT Contact_Code
        FROM Core.Contacts
        WHERE
        Contact_Code LIKE UPPER(left(First_Name,2) ||
        CASE    
            WHEN Middle_Name IS NULL THEN left(Last_Name,3) 
            ELSE left(Middle_Name,1) || left(Last_Name,2) 
        END || '%')
        ORDER BY Contact_Code desc)
   WHERE ROWNUM=1;
BEGIN
    open contact_cursor;
    fetch contact_cursor into C_Code;
    close contact_cursor;

    IF C_Code IS NULL THEN
    Ret_Val := 
    UPPER(left(First_Name,2)||
        CASE    
            WHEN Middle_Name IS NULL THEN left(Last_Name,3) 
            ELSE left(Middle_Name,1) || left(Last_Name,2) 
        END
    )
       || '-' || '0001'; 
    ELSE
        Ret_Val := 
        UPPER(left(First_Name,2)||
            CASE    
                WHEN Middle_Name IS NULL THEN left(Last_Name,3) 
                ELSE left(Middle_Name,1) || left(Last_Name,2) 
            END
        )
           || '-' ||
              trim(to_char(CAST(right(C_Code,4) AS integer)+1,'0000')); 
    END IF;

    RETURN Ret_Val;
END;
/

show errors;
```

When I execute the query, it says:

```
Warning: compiled but with compilation errors
No errors.
```

But when I omit the schema Core in the definition

```
CREATE FUNCTION Get_Contact_Code
```

it compiles.

Any ideas why Oracle behaves this way?

Comment: why are you logged in as sys?

Comment: I am creating database via script, creating/altering/dropping users hence and thence, this is development environment. So, I am working as sys.

Comment: Ever heard of "definer rights" of stored procedures? Compiling PL/SQL code as SYS is a bad idea.

Comment: @Codo, thanks. I am new to oracle. My database is a .sql file which will drop and load schema/users, tables, views, packages, and procedures on target database. For testing and developing (on my single machine), I drop/recreate/compile users and associated objects on every major change, to see that everything works well. But in production, the .sql file will be run only once by a user with necessary rights to create the database. What is the best practice, please guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What are LEFT and RIGHT?  Does your script not include the schema name for those functions, so they only get installed in SYS and not in CORE?

Comment: Thanks jonearles, I should have schema qualified the functions left and right, or should have created those in the schema core. Got it, thanks.

Comment: @jonearles, why did the database engine show the message "no errors, when there was an error" and nothing in SYS.USER_ERRORS?

Comment: @Nick Binnet: I'm not sure why the errors don't show up, I can't reproduce that behavior.  The best possible explanation I have is that when you add objects to SYS weird things can happen.  If you don't want to deal with permission issues on dev you're probably better off with `grant dba to [user]` than using SYS.

Comment: @jonearles - granting a powerful set of privileges to a user account is generally a bad idea and not to be encouraged.  It is all very well saying "it's just DEV" but not sorting out the correct permissions in development inevitably leads to the DBA role being required in LIVE.  Seen it too many times to believe otherwise.  Track the specific required permissions and keep them in a GRANT script which can be deployed in each subsequent environment.

Comment: @jonearles - Although I agree the habitual use of SYS is a bad idea too.

Comment: @jonearles - Nick Binnet explained it best "The best possible explanation I have is that when you add objects to SYS weird things can happen." Tom Kyte of AskTom explains this when using dual as a test case: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1562813956388